# Grok formatting for a custom timestamp

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

```
2015-03-13 00:23:37.616
```

I try using to use grok to format the following date format. I have tried:

SYSLOGTIMESTAMP,
DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG,
DATESTAMP_RFC2822

with no success. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timestamp you mentioned can be matched by Logstash with the `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601` pattern.

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match}"]
    }
}
```

You can test this at the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) by entering `2015-03-13 00:23:37.616` and `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match}`

You probably want to match into a different field name, but that's the basic idea.

Built-in patterns can be found in the [Logstash documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok), or on [GitHub](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core).

Comment: Why does Grok Debugger give me all this additional info? `"YEAR": [
    [
      "2015"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "03"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "13"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "00",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "00",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "38.582"
    ]
  ],`

Comment: I implemented this into my filter file and I did not get the extra attributes which is what matters. Thanks rutter.

Comment: @pcproff If you select "Named Captures Only", those should go away (that's the default behavior in grok, but not in the debugger). Those other matches are the subpatterns that make up `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601`. Sometimes handy to see them when you're exploring, but otherwise they can be noisy.